# Where should I store a list of select options in Rails 3?

Tags: localization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Using Rails 3.1.3 and Ruby 1.9.3.

I want to give the user a list of possible date/time formats. The user's selection will be stored in the Users table. Date/time values are then formatted using the I18n.localize function. I actually have 10 formats; here by way of example are the first two:

**config/locales/datetime.en.yml**

```
en:
  time:
    format_labels:
      mdyslash12: mm/dd/yyyy - hh:mm am (12-hour)
      mdyslash24: mm/dd/yyyy - hh:mm (24-hour)
    formats:
      mdyslash12: ! '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p'
      mdyslash24: ! '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
```

My question is where to store the list of possible date/time formats. I've identified three possibilities.

#### 1. List options as a CONSTANT in model:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
DATETIME_FORMATS = %w[mdyslash12 mdyslash24]
validates :datetime_format, :presence => true,
          :inclusion => { :in => DATETIME_FORMATS }
```

#### 2. Create an application constant and validate against that:

**config/initializers/constants.rb**

```
Rails.configuration.datetime_formats = "mdyslash12 mdyslash24"
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
validates :datetime_format, :presence => true,
          :inclusion => { :in => Rails.application.config.datetime_formats.split(" ") }
```

#### 3. Validate directly against the locale file:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
validates :datetime_format, :presence => true,
          :inclusion => { :in => (I18n.t 'time.format_labels').stringify_keys.keys }
```

This option uses a feature that is new to me:  `I18n.t 'time.format_labels'` returns a hash of ALL keys and values from that branch of the locale file.  The hash keys are symbols, so to get a string array, I call `stringify_keys` to convert the symbols to strings, then `keys` to give me only the keys (no values).

Option #3 is the DRYest in that I don't have to list the possible values in two places. But it doesn't feel quite right to depend on the locale file for the discreet list of possible date/time formats.

What would you recommend? One of these options? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with option 1 to start with, since it's simple, clear, and fairly DRY.  I might refactor to option 2 if I ended up needing that constant in another model.

Option 3 has the potential to behave differently based on the locale, so I don't like that.  If you end up forgetting to specify your format labels in a new locale, your selection list might end up being empty (or if there's a typo in one locale, it might take longer to notice, since the typo would be treated as valid for that locale).   Regardless it's probably a good idea to unittest this in all your supported locales.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Funny, I started with option 1 but then I thought, datetime is like time zone; it shouldn't be bound to one model, so I started mucking around until I got to option 3.

In my original question, I didn't actually get into the SELECT lists in the Views, but I'm leaning towards generating those directly from the locale files, similar to option 3.  My thinking is that my model might ultimately accept, say, 20 datetime formats, but a given locale may only implement 8 or 12.  Thoughts?

Comment: I think that actually makes sense as well, as long as you're willing to put up with the added complexity (I started thinking about some of those cases after posting my answer).  The key is making sure that if a user changes they're locale and they're date/time selection isn't supported in the new locale things still work.  Also, if you're just using numeric settings, then the settings might not *really* belong in the locale (e.g. I'm a Spanish speaker in the US so I want a US date format).  I usually end up doing the pragmatic/simple thing in these cases, to avoid added complexity.

Comment: Good points, especially if the user is allowed to change their own locale. I could just pull the SELECT collection from the model as well, and if a translation is missing in the locale, it'll just throw an error. I'm not actually planning on multiple locales at first but the locale files have proven to be an easy way to store lookup strings, plus they have the bonus of preparing for localization down the road.